# Как сделать автоматический логин в консоль Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, автозапуск

Требуется чтобы при загрузке машины линукс (Ubuntu 10) автоматически логинился как рут в консоли. Графической оболочки нет никакой.

Расскажите как это делается?
В интернете информации минимум и вся устаревшая.

Comment: Это нужно сделать для "удобства" ?  (Тогда это сильно компромитирует систему)  или Это нужно для выполнения определеных задачь? ( Тогда логинится в консоль не обязательно).

Comment: @Yaroslav Да, это надо для выполнения конкретных задач. Это плата, на которой при включении автоматически должен выполняться скрипт/подниматься иксы/запускаться ПО. На данный момент это все происходит по логину и прописано в ./bashrc . Осталось залогинится :) Насчет секьюрности можно не переживать сети на ней нету, клавы тоже.

Comment: Возможно Вам , нужно корректно настроить систему автоматического запуска ? а не автоматически вводить логин/пароль

Comment: @Yaroslav а можно стартовать иксы не залогинившись? И какой .xinitrc будет тогда выполнятся?

Comment: воспользуйтесь скриптом [`/etc/rc.local`](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=rc.local+is%3Aa)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, если дистр с системд, то рцлокал не пашет. Надо или его разрешить или сервис писать.

Comment: @donRumata вы очень правы :) Потому очень бы хотелось все таки найти ответ на начальный вопрос.

Comment: @donRumata, только что проверил. `/etc/rc.local` отлично выполнился. потому, что скрипт `/etc/init.d/rc.local` присутствует в [пакете *initscripts*](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/initscripts/filelist), симв. ссылка на него есть в `/etc/rc2.d`, который обрабатывается скриптом `/etc/init.d/rc 2`, который systemd должен выполнять при загрузке. вероятно, либо у вас что-то в этой цепочке «разорвано», либо она слишком сильно отличается от debian-овской.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, хз как на счёт дебиана, а на 16.04 убунте с последними версиями пакетов не пашет.

Comment: А из графона только xorg или lightdm есть\можно поставить?

Comment: @donRumata, ну, с вашей-то версией убунты [всё понятно](http://askubuntu.com/q/765120/416190), а вот в чём именно заключается проблема у автора — неясно.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### предуведомление:

это ответ непосредственно на вопрос, а автору вопроса, судя по содержанию комментариев, требуется совсем-совсем другое — выяснить, по какой причине у него не выполняется скрипт `/etc/rc.local`. но это абсолютно другой вопрос.

---

> В интернете информации минимум и вся устаревшая.

это не совсем верно. много лет в популярных дистрибутивах на нескольких первых (как правило — с первого по шестой) виртуальных терминалах обычно запускаются одни и те же программы *agetty* или *mingetty*.

и обе они имеют опцию `--autologin имя-пользователя` (некоторые реализации — `-a имя-пользователя`), которая делает именно то, что следует из её названия.

другое дело, что не всегда просто определить, где именно находится файл, в котором описан запуск `*getty`. чтобы добавить опцию к вызову нужного экземпляра `*getty`.

1. в «старой доброй» *sysv*-инициализации это, естественно, файл `/etc/inittab`:

   ```
   $ grep -v '^#' /etc/inittab | grep getty
   1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
   2:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty2
   3:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty3
   4:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty4
   5:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty5
   6:23:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty6
   ```
2. в системе инициализации *upstart* эту роль играют, судя по всему, файлы `/etc/init/tty?.conf`:

   ```
   $ grep -v '^#' /etc/init/tty?.conf | grep getty
   /etc/init/tty1.conf:exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
   /etc/init/tty2.conf:exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
   /etc/init/tty3.conf:exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
   /etc/init/tty4.conf:exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
   /etc/init/tty5.conf:exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
   /etc/init/tty6.conf:exec /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
   ```
3. в системе инициализации *systemd* ситуация [несколько сложнее](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html). насколько я понял, глядя на debian-овскую конфигурацию, надо заменить символическую ссылку `/etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service`, которая ссылается на файл универсального сервиса `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`, на реальный файл (с тем же именем — `getty@tty1.service`). можно скопировать содержимое того же самого `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`, и добавить вышеупомянутую опцию к вызову программы `*getty`.

   зачем подменять, а не исправлять сразу файл с универсальным сервисом `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service`? для того, чтобы при переключении на другие виртуальные терминалы (не *tty1*) программа `*getty` запускалась «по-старому», и предлагала «обычное» приглашение к вводу логина/пароля.

Comment: На самом деле моя проблема звучит так. У нас в старых проектах сделан автологин -> запуск иксов, и мне надо сделать так же. Но в старых сборках я так и не нашла (не знаю где искать?) этот автологин. Теперь у меня есть ваш способ перед глазами для примера. Спасибо за ответ!