# Как при загрузке linux выполнить произвольную команду?

Tags: linux, bash, debian, systemd

Вопрос по факту о подобии автозагрузки в linux.

Работает на сервере php-скрипт в фоновом режиме. В ДЦ отключали сервер ночью. Как сделать так что бы после включения и загрузки ОС она опять сама запустила бы этот скрипт? Вероятно нужна команда на bash, её надо сохранить в файл, а файл либо положить в какую-то папку либо запускать при старте. Система Debian 8

Comment: См. /etc/init.d/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Автозагрузка jar при старте CentOS6](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538005/%d0%90%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-jar-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5-centos6)

Comment: В Debian 8 по умолчанию в качестве системы инициализации systemd

Comment: @DmitryErohin, и [что это меняет](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/591993/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-linux#comment795804_591993)?

Comment: мой комментарий был адресован Yaant

Comment: @DmitryErohin, нельзя сказать, что Yaant совсем не прав: есть такая штука как «обратная совместимость». посмотрите, например, ответы к этому вопросу: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/233468/110559

Comment: зачем костыли в виде init когда есть systemd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создай файл `/etc/systemd/system/php-script-4-autostart.service` с таким содержимым:

```
[Unit]
# Чисто камент для человека.
Description=Autostart my php script
# Запускать скрипт после того как поднимется сеть
After=network.target

[Service]
# Хз что это, но оно пашет
Type=oneshot
# Не помню, но нужно для предыдущей строки.
RemainAfterExit=yes

# Собсно путь до скрипта.
ExecStart=/path/to/php-script.php
# Под каким пользователем и группой он будет выполняться. Секурность, вся фигня.
User=www-data
Group=www-data

[Install]
# Аналог Runlevel
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

А потом разреши запускаться при старте системы:

```
systemctl enable php-script-4-autostart.service
```

Comment: пятнадцать строк текста и одна команда вместо [одной-единственной строки](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538081/178576).

Comment: systemd - это уже стандарт нравится кому-то это или не нравится. При создании сервиса как в моём ответе - можно стартовать, останавливать, смотреть статус и запрещать загрузку проги\скрипта через стандартные комманды. `rc.local` - имхо костыль и подходит для грязных хаков вида: "ща потестим, если пашет, то будем делать уже красиво".